# Determining the number of operators (random effect) for a two-way chi-square test

Tags: categorical-data, random-effects-model, statistical-power

I am designing a study to benchmark a new measurement technique with two traditional measurement techniques. Let's call the new technique N and the two traditional techniques T1 and T2. It is believed that the obtained accuracy is dependent on the experience level of the operator for the two traditional techniques, but not for the new technique.

The purpose of the study is two fold:

1. Compare the overall accuracy for the three techniques.
2. Compare the dependency of experience for the three techniques.

To make it a little more complicated, the measurements are categorical and there is no ground truth as this is an in-vivo study. To overcome this, a validation step follows the measurements. The assumption for this validation step is that, given the three measurements, a human can tell which of the measurement is the better fitting one (this assumptions is going to be validated separately). The output of the experiment is hence a score for each method counting the number of times it returned the best fitting measurement.

If the methods are equally good they will each receive 1/3 of the "best fits". If one method is more accurate than the others, it will receive a higher percentage.

The output of the experiment is organized in a table with the "best fit" scores for each method and for the two group of operators (the data in the table is just made up for illustration purposes).

```
   | High experience | Low experience |
---+----------------------------------+
N  |       100       |        200     |
T1 |       110       |         40     |
T2 |        90       |         60     |
---+-----------------+----------------+
```

The null-hypothesis that all methods are equal, meaning that the methods are equally accurate and equally dependent on experience of the operate, could be tested with a chi-square test. I want to generalize the conclusion to all operators and not just the ones participating in the experiment.

The number of samples can easily be found through a power analysis for the chi-square test, but what about the number of operators? Do I need 10, 20 or hundreds of operators? How do I go about determining this?

Maybe the problem is that my test statistic is not suitable for the question I am asking. Had this been continuous variables (normal distributed), I could have performed an ANOVA with operator as a "random effect". This would allow me to generalize the results obtained for the particular set of operators to the whole population of operators. The ANOVA power analysis would need an estimate of the operator-to-operator variance and from this an estimate of number of operators could be found.

Is there something similar for categorical variables and how do I go about estimating the number of operators I need?